# Get the selected input type radio button ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, radio-button

I have two radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" />1
<input type="radio" name="group1" />2
```

How do I know which one is selected when the form is posted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inputs should have values:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />1
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" />2
```

Then, the value will be posted on the name `group1`. On Asp.net you can get it using:

```
Request.Form["group1"]
```

Comment: Request.Form["group1"] returns null !

Comment: Try `Request["group1"]` to make sure. If that doesn't work you're posting it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using runat="server", it can happen that name attribute is changed at client, so you will get null as value.